# Indexing two lists and comparing their values

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

I'm working on a datetime validation project. Specifically, making sure there is a datetime at every interval. If a datetime is missing from the interval, I add the missing values to the list of Timestamp objects.

When I run the below code, it marks most of the datetimes as Missing even if they aren't. I believe this is an indexing issue. Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
import datetime

_RRATE_ = [0,1,0] #data refresh rate in [minute, hour, day]
LOCALE = "Seattle" #location of cell site

timesList = [] #initialize list of Timestamps with Errors filled in



#Class Timestamp allows us to store all data for a single timestamp in one object.
class Timestamp:
    x = 1 #gives each new timestamp object a unique identifier for the dataset
    missingStamps = 0
    def __init__(self, datetime, location, errorMessage):
        self.timestamp = datetime
        self.location = location
        self.error = errorMessage
        self.UID = Timestamp.x
        Timestamp.x+=1
        timesList.append(self)

    def updateError(self, newError):
        self.error = newError

    def __repr__(self): #make print timesList look neat
        return str(self.UID) + " " + str(self.timestamp) + ", " + self.location + ", " + self.error

def duplicates(index):
    tempList = []
    for timestamp in timesList:
        tempList.append(timestamp.timestamp)
    if datetimes[index] in tempList:
        Timestamp(datetimes[index],LOCALE, "duplicate")
        return True
    else:
        return False

def outOfPlace(index):
    for timestampObj in timesList:
        if(timestampObj.timestamp > datetimes[index]):
            Timestamp(datetimes[index],LOCALE, "out of place")
            return True
        else:
            return False

def missingTimestamp(datetimeObj):
    Timestamp.missingStamps = 0
    if dateAdd(timesList[len(timesList)-1].timestamp) < datetimeObj:
        while dateAdd(timesList[len(timesList)-1].timestamp) < datetimeObj:
            Timestamp(dateAdd(timesList[len(timesList)-1].timestamp), LOCALE, "missing timestamp")
            Timestamp.missingStamps+=1
        return True
    else:
        return False

def dateAdd(datetimeObj):
    return (datetimeObj + datetime.timedelta(minutes = _RRATE_[0], hours = _RRATE_[1], days = _RRATE_[2]))

def main():
    Timestamp(datetimes[0],LOCALE, "no error")
    errorCount = 0
    for i in range(1,len(datetimes)):
        if duplicates(i):
            errorCount+=1
        elif outOfPlace(i):
            errorCount+=1
        elif (missingTimestamp(datetimes[i]))>0:
            errorCount+=Timestamp.missingStamps
            Timestamp.missingStamps = 0
        else:
            Timestamp(datetimes[i],LOCALE, "no error")
    for elem in timesList:
        print elem



b = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20)
c = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,1)
d = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,2)
e = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,7)
f = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,7)
g = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,9)
h = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,16)
i = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,16)
j = datetime.datetime(2018,7,20,9)

datetimes = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]

main()
```

[What is printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n6bt.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

As specified by @Prune in the comments to your question you should give a more complete description of the problem.

That being said, I ran your code and from the output I got, the problem seems to be in the logic of the control flow statements in the main function, specifically:

```
elif (missingTimestamp(datetimes[i]))>0:
        errorCount+=Timestamp.missingStamps
        Timestamp.missingStamps = 0
```

When missing timestamps are encountered e.g. between `d` and `e`, the `missingTimestamp` function fills in the values up to `e`, but `e` is not included and the control block does not take care of this after the function returns. It then moves to `f`, and `e` was not placed in your global `timesList` variable.

A simple solution to the problem is to change the `elif` block to:

```
        elif (missingTimestamp(datetimes[i]))>0:
        errorCount+=Timestamp.missingStamps
        Timestamp.missingStamps = 0
        # Line below to add current value to global timeList variable
        Timestamp(datetimes[i],LOCALE, "no error")
```